FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/popup-closed-by-user)
I'm coding a Pixel Wars for me and my friends. So I'm trying to implement an account system there so that me and them can each have our own nickname, ...
So I use Google's Firebase authentication to create an identification/connection system.
After coding it, I wanted to make a first attempt to upload to my website with the Hostinger platform. So I tried to log into my account to see if everything worked, however the following error occurred:
`FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/popup-closed-by-user).
FirebaseError errors.ts:76
  create errors.ts:134
  createErrorInternal assert.ts:161
  _createError assert.ts:86
  pollId popup.ts:298
  setTimeout handler*poll popup.ts:297
  setTimeout handler*poll popup.ts:203
  pollUserCancellation popup.ts:203
  onExecution popup.ts:266
  execute abstract_popup_redirect_operation.ts:77
  execute abstract_popup_redirect_operation.ts:72
  executeNotNull popup.ts:224
  signInWithPopup popup.ts:133
  <anonymous> auth.js:21
  EventListener.handleEvent* auth.js:20
auth.js:32:17
  <anonymous> https://****.fr/pixel-war/auth.js:32
  (Async: promise callback)
  <anonymous> https://****.fr/pixel-war/auth.js:28
  (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
  <anonymous> https://****.fr/pixel-war/auth.js:20`

I have no idea where this could come from. I tried to add my domain name to the authorized domains, then I did some research but I couldn't find anyone who could solve my problem.
Here is my problem briefly described, if you need more information in order to solve my problem, do not hesitate to ask me because being a beginner with Firebase, I don't really know what to provide.
Thanks in advance to whoever finds the solution!
I tried changing the allowed domains settings on Firebase, I tried changing the OAUTH credentials in case it was wrong. I tried to find videos explaining the error and what changes to the code or Firebase tool. However, research on this topic is limited and therefore difficult to resolve.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7807

I'd recommend avoiding the popup sign-in method
